# Q: Will Kendo UI for Angular 2 Grid have export functionality (e.g. XSLX)?

Tags: export, xlsx, kendo-ui-angular2

Is planned to have export implemented in Kendo UI for Angular 2, like the one available in ASP .MVC suite? 
Or do we have to use the one in your C# Wrappers ( MVC, WebForms etc. )?

Answer (score 1):

I guess at some point this functionality will be added. You can track the roadmap here:

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/roadmap/